# JSON: Keys and Field Names: Dynamically Parse

Tags: json, dynamic

I have a JSON string

```
    {"key": "2021-01-01 22:59:59", "data": {"field1": "newvalue1", "field2": "newvalue2"}}
```

I have to morph this json into the following:

```
    {
        "field1": {"before": "oldValue1", "new": "newvalue1"},
        "field2": {"before": "oldValue2", "new": "newvalue2"}
    }
```

The problem is that field1 and field2 are not always present. THe original JSON is dynamically generated by a DevExtreme DataGrid's Updates to a row. This is how far I got:

EDIT:
The below code works

```
    var outputJSON = {};
    var changes = {"field1": "newvalue1", "field2": "newvalue2"};
    for(var i = 0; i < Object.keys(changes).length; i++){
        var keyName = Object.keys(changes)[i];
        outputJSON[keyName] = {};

        outputJSON[keyName]["before"] = Object.values(changes)[0];
        outputJSON[keyName]["after"] = Object.values(changes)[1];
    }
    console.log(JSON.stringify(outputJSON));
```

I think this is closer to what I need.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Working code:

```
    var keys = Object.keys(JSON.stringify(changes));
            for (var i = 0; i < Object.keys(changes).length; i++) {
                var fieldName = Object.keys(changes)[i];
                inputJSON[fieldName] = {};
                inputJSON[fieldName]["before"] = editRow[fieldName];
                inputJSON[fieldName]["after"] = (changes)[fieldName];
            }
```